# MongoDB is showing too many connections open

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-cluster

I was looking at the MongoDB logs and it was showing something like:

[LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Successfully connected to mongo1 (**13795 connections now open** to mongo1 with a 0 second timeout)

This is a connection made by a secondary node in a cluster to the primary node.

Can someone help me to understand what does it mean by "**13795 connections now open**"?

I got help from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/gXTXtOaA_dc/LgKauuVSCAAJ), but not much use in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if are there a lot of concurreny updates without data indexed that causes documents changing location constantly. If positive make sure using upsertid because always indexed.